# Parsing Error while parsing last-Modified Date

Tags: java, android

I am not really sure, what's wrong. Here is my code:

```
String lastModifiedString = connection.getHeaderField("Last-Modified"); //Wed, 10 Oct 2018 10:57:42 GMT
Log.d("OUTPUT", lastModifiedString);
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.getDefault());
Date lastModifiedDate = format.parse(lastModifiedString);
System.out.println(lastModifiedDate);
```

But I am always getting in Logcat:

```
D/OUTPUT: Wed, 10 Oct 2018 10:21:45 GMT
E/Error @ NewsletterLates: Unparseable date: "Wed, 10 Oct 2018 10:21:45 GMT" (at offset 0)
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 10 Oct 2018 10:21:45 GMT" (at offset 0)
W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
    at bdk.de.bdk_app.NewsletterLatestReleaseGetter.doInBackground(NewsletterLatestReleaseGetter.java:48)
    at bdk.de.bdk_app.NewsletterLatestReleaseGetter.doInBackground(NewsletterLatestReleaseGetter.java:16)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Hopefully someone can see, what I am not seeing!

Edit 1: Apparently the error only occurs on my real device and not in the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be getting a different locale on your emulator and your real device 
using `Locale.getDefault()`.

Try using

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ROOT);
```

Comment: Fixed it by changing the Locale to .US.